# npm - Issue to force npm run jasmine from local node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

**I installed jasmine npm module as global**. Later on, with the purpose of sharing code and make easy for the team to have all dependencies, **I installed jasmine locally to the project using --save-dev.**

**Issue is that it tries to exec from node_modules global one instead of local one.**

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tdd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing tdd practices",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "$(npm bin)/jasmine"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test",
    "tdd",
    "jasmine",
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

If my **tests are passing I get no errors**. In case a **test does not pass, I get an error pointing to the global node_modules.**

```
Albertos-MBP:TDD albertof$ npm run test

> tdd@1.0.0 test /Users/albertof/Projects/Web/TDD
> jasmine

Started
......FF

Failures:
1) Html Replacement Regex: should replace . in src attributes for <img src="./hello.jpg"> 
  Message:
    Expected '<img static/hello.jpg">' to be '<img src="static/hello.jpg">'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected '<img static/hello.jpg">' to be '<img src="static/hello.jpg">'.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/albertof/Projects/Web/TDD/spec/htmlSpec.js:22:62)

8 specs, 1 failures
Finished in 0.015 seconds

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/albertof/npm-global/bin/npm" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tdd@1.0.0 test: `jasmine`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tdd@1.0.0 test script 'jasmine'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tdd package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     jasmine
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs tdd
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls tdd
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/albertof/Projects/Web/TDD/npm-debug.log
```

**What is the reason to try to execute from the global node_modules installed?**
Running `npm bin` return the local one for the current project `/Users/albertof/Projects/Web/TDD/node_modules/.bin`

Answer (score 1):

edit your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "$(npm bin)/jasmine; exit 0"
}
```